# Replacing Typeahead enabled input field value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead

I am trying to replace Typeahead enabled input field value using jQuery. But after replacing the value when I click on the input field then it changed the value to original selected value.

If I select "US - DC" then using jQuery it display "US".

If I click on the input field then it replace the value "US" with the value "US - DC"!

I am using following code-

```
$("#country-id").bind("change", function(e){
var country = $(this).val();

var t = $(this);

$.ajax({
    url: './state',
    type: 'post',
    data: 'id='+country,
    cache: false,
    dataType:'json',

    success: function(data) {
        var countryVal = country.split("-",1);
        console.log(countryVal);
        t.val(countryVal);
    }
 })  
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You make an ajax request and the success function does nothing with the response data? I assume that's your issue.

Comment: please create a demo on http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
jQuery("#btnClick").on("click", function(){
    var countryVal = jQuery("#testInp").val().split("-", 1);
    console.log(countryVal);
    jQuery("#testResult").val(countryVal);
});
```

You can check this in jsfiddle -> 
http://jsfiddle.net/ChoHongRae/zvkkb5fr/1/

Comment: Thanks. The approach work for normal input field but for Typeahead enabled input field it behaviour differently like how I mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$("#country-id").typeahead('val', countryVal)` instead of `t.val(countryVal)` as long as "country-id" is the id of the typeahead bounded input.